# Couldn't move app in Android 4.1 emulator

Tags: sd-card, 4.1-jelly-bean, app2sd, android-emulator

I am unable to move an app to the SD Card in Android 4.1 on an emulator. It is working fine in other versions (Android 2.3.3 to Android 4.0.3). In Android 4.1 it's giving dialog "couldn't move app".

Even if I am trying to move app directly from emulator settings (Settings->Apps->App info->Move to SD card) then also it's giving same error.

Is it a bug or security feature?

Comment: Which Android device is this? Many newer devices since ICS comes with a single partition for everything so move to SD becomes unnecessary.

Comment: Device is Samsung galaxy s3. But if it is device specific issue then it should work fine in emulator. Is these new version of android(i.e. Android 4.1) has provided any changes in SD card related features?